# Unknown error when mounting USB

Tags: usb, mount, 22.10

I have two Ubuntu accounts. In most of the time I use the USB on my main account. I recorded some files from the other account and now I can't open the pendrive (on both accounts). I get the message "Unable to access..." and "Unknown error when mounting USB".
I tried  `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda`, it didn't work(the USB is in ntfs format). Tested it on Windows 11 and it works fine.

**Edit:**
Running chkdsk with Windows 11 fixed the issue. I think it is something that has to do with how Ubuntu deals with USB permissions. For example, when I put my USB in my main profile, and then switch user, I have to eject it and put it back in to open it. And sometimes I can't open files written in the secondary profile, they seem damaged.

Comment: 1. It's unlikely it has NTFS. FAT32 or ExFAT are the typical file systems for USB flash media. 2. Either way use the error corrections tools in Windows to check it, just in case. 3. Make sure you eject it properly in Windows. If you shutdown Windows with the USB connected -and- Fast Startup enabled (default) the drive may beacome unreadable in other systems due to hibernation. 4. If ExFAT and you're using an old Ubuntu release yoiu may need to install support for it. This is pretty much all you need to know and all you should have posted, otherwise the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Upvoted for `ntfsfix`, which fixed the issue I was having. (I knew for sure mine was NTFS because I formatted it less than an hour ago.)